# How can I prevent the game from blasting loud music during the "PRESS ANY BUTTON" screen?

Tags: sword-art-online-fatal-bullet

I have the music volume set to 1 in the settings, yet the game increases the volume to 10 on the "PRESS ANY BUTTON" screen.

How can I prevent this from happening?